# Executing more than one command with ssh2 exec

Tags: ssh, command, exec

I have a script that runs one command. Based on that result, I can run the next command. Steps:run first script it puts me in global then from global I will run the next command.
First command:
$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, 'config global');
After this result I should run this cause I need to go into global
$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, 'get hardware cpu');

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this

```
$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, 'command1;command2');
```

Comment: It only executes the first one:`$stream = ssh2_exec($connection, 'config global;get hardware cpu');
stream_set_blocking($stream, true);

echo "Output: " . stream_get_contents($stream);
fclose($stream);`